# Convert HTML string to PDF with MigraDoc

Tags: html, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am fetching HTML content from database and trying to create a PDF doc using the following code

```
 paragraph = Document.LastSection.AddParagraph();
 paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
 paragraph.AddFormattedText(AuditSummary);
```

But raw HTML is emitted to PDF as shown here:

[image]

How can I add the same string with proper formatting?

Comment: As you know, those libraries cannot do that. However, [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document) can, you should check it out instead. What you would need to do is create a new DocumentModel object, call DocumentModel.Content.LoadText(string, HtmlLoadOptions) method and last call the DocumentModel.Save(string, PdfSaveOptions) method, literally that is all you need.

Comment: This library is not free.is there any open source free library to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not to my knowledge. There are open source projects that can read HTML and there are open source projects that can write PDF, but I'm not aware of any free solution that can do both. So what you would need to do is choose two and combine them. If you have a simple HTML content, and a simple styling then this could be an easy task, but the more complex your HTML and CSS is the more time this will take you to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither MigraDoc nor PDFsharp parse HTML.

It is up to you to parse the HTML and replace it with MigraDoc calls like `AddFormattedText()`.

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx#Can_I_use_PDFsharp_to_convert_HTML_or_RTF_to_PDF_10

Comment: To add to this answer, for an idea on how to actually parse the html and get it into your MigraDoc document, please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68939953/413785