# How to parse HTML text and add it to MigraDoc Document

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I need to get a text that's being written by a user (in CKEditor HTML), and then add that text to a MigraDoc document, as a paragraph or whatever I need it to be.

My idea was converting the text to an MDDDL document (in memory) and add it to the document. But I don't know if there are any DLLs that permit that behaviour.

So, my question is, can someone give me pointers or advice on how I could make this happen? Should I parse the HMTL text? If so, to what should I parse it? How can I add it afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MigraDoc / PDFSharp can't do this.

But, you could use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) nuget and then use its `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()` to pull out the pieces of text from html in a flat list kind of a structure, and `node.ParentNode.Name` to figure out the tag that the text is wrapped in. And then insert the text into your MigraDoc document with something like `.AddFormattedText()` and apply custom MigraDoc styles to it - i.e. if the parent tag is "strong" then apply a MigraDoc style where `Font.Italic = true;` etc..

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but just wanted to not leave this unanswered. I ended up using a solution based on your recomendation, I found [this git repo](https://github.com/benfoster/MigraDoc.Extensions) and just expanded on it for my use case. Since this answer was what made me reach my desired result, Im marking it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Neither PDFsharp nor MigraDoc can parse HTML, so either write your own code or try to find a third-party library (which may not exist yet).

I would probably convert the HTML directly to MigraDoc document objects in memory.

Comment: What procedure should I take to, as you said, convert the HTML directly to MigraDoc document objects in memory?

Comment: As of now this is a project that needs to be finished in a question of weeks, so I don't think I can afford to write a complex parser. If the data source was XML or XHTML would the answer still be the same?

Comment: To keep it simple: You can convert RTF to MigraDoc or come up with your own Wiki or Markdown syntax. We "parse" RTF by means of a RichEdit control where we select a single character and query its attributes. We also use Wiki code that can be converted to MigraDoc. It's all closed source and I cannot share it. Which attributes do you need? Regular, bold, italics, maybe underline. Define which attributes you support and parse them from HTML or RTF or Wiki or Markdown - that shouldn't take very long to implement.

Comment: okok, but how do I add the rtf text to the document in migradoc?

and thank you for your help btw.

Comment: Call `AddParagraph()` and then call `AddFormattedText`. In the best case you call `AddFormattedText` whenever a supported attribute changes. For a simple implementation you can call `AddFormattedText` for each character, but that will increase the overhead.